# open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) for Reading Excel File

Tags: excel, file, apache-poi, readfile

for hours i tried to fix this Problem.

I Have an Activity which should Read my Excel Document, which i saved in my Project Folder under "C:/Users/.../src/main/assets/test.xlsx".

I've never worked with "APACHE POI" to read Excel Files.

Maybe one Of you can solve this problem :)

```
class ActivityExcel : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_excel)

        val inputStream = FileInputStream(File("C:/Users/.../src/main/assets/test.xlsx"))
        //Instantiate Excel workbook using existing file:
        val xlWb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream)

        //Row index specifies the row in the worksheet (starting at 0):
        val rowNumber = 0
        //Cell index specifies the column within the chosen row (starting at 0):
        val columnNumber = 0

        //Get reference to first sheet:
        val xlWs = xlWb.getSheetAt(0)
        println(xlWs.getRow(rowNumber).getCell(columnNumber))
    }
}
```

But if i want to open the Activity, i get the error:Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Would be thankfull if anyone can helps me :)
MinSDK: 26
CompilseSDK: 30

Comment: It seems unlikely that `c:/Users/` is going to be valid on an Android device - shouldn't that be a storage or similar uri?